# Bootstrap 3, how disable auto-added Glyphicon?

Tags: drupal, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use Bootstrap (v3) with Drupal 8. When I create a button named "**Search** something", bootstrap adds automatically a "Search" Glyphicon. I do some web searches, but I don't find how "disable" (or hide?) the 'search'auto-added glyphicon of my button.

When I create a sample submit button from a Form Class custom module :

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
...
$form['submit'] = [
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#value' => 'Search something',
];
```

If I go to the page where there is my form, the button have automatically a magnifying glass glyphicon :

[image]

I want display my button without any glyphicon, how can I do that ? I must add a class to my button ? which ?

Thank you !

Comment: Can you share your code.. ? as per my knowledge unless you don't add the class glyphicon glyphicon-search the button is not changed to glyphicon search. its a normal button..

Comment: I updated the light version of my code :)

Comment: can you check the html part of the page...

Comment: @spacecodeur have you found a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample code for "glyphicon glyphicon-search". Check the classes that are added to the button, it cannot add automatically- there is nothing magic.

Hope this helps..

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<p>normal button without Glyphicon icon: <span class="btn btn-default">button </span></p>

<p>Search icon: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></p>

<p>Search icon on a button:
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
  </button>
</p>

<p>Search icon on a styled button:
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
  </button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had success adding the following to my form element:

```
'#icon' => array('none'),
```

So the whole thing would look like:

```
$form['submit'] = [
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#value' => 'Search something',
  '#icon' => array('none'),
];
```